# Internal Server Error when using Flask session

Tags: python, session, cookies, flask

I want to save an ID between requests, using Flask `session` cookie, but I'm getting an `Internal Server Error` as result, when I perform a request.

I prototyped a simple Flask app for demonstrating my problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from flask import Flask, session

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def run():
    session['tmp'] = 43
    return '43'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Why I can't  store the `session` cookie with the following value when I perform the request?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @sberry I'm getting "no secret key was set" error.  But I thought (clearly incorrectly) that that was set automatically

Answer (score 51, accepted):

According to [Flask sessions documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#sessions):

> ...
>   What this means is that the user could look at the contents of your
>   cookie but not modify it, unless they know the secret key used for
>   signing.
>
> In order to use sessions you **have to set a secret key**.

Set *secret key*. And you should return string, not int.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from flask import Flask, session

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def run():
    session['tmp'] = 43
    return '43'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'A0Zr98j/3yX R~XHH!jmN]LWX/,?RT'
    app.run()
```

Comment: @falstru Thanks, the 43 int was a typo.  You'll get the answer when the time limit is up

Comment: You may want to generate the secret key from a random source instead of codify-ing it.  The secret key size matters too. Try SECRET_KEY = open("/dev/random","rb").read(32) . See http://andorian.blogspot.com/2014/08/flask-or-itsdangerous-secret-key-size.html

Comment: @Lmwangi, Actually I used `os.urandom` to generate the random bytes, and filtered printable one. BTW, if you always generate ranodm number every time you run the server, you'll have problems. For example, if you have multiple instance of flask, every instances will have difference secret key.

Comment: @falsetru: Yup I agree. In fact, at work, we cache the secret to a file and read the file at startup.

Comment: It may be worth noting that when coming across this issue, if one sets their `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` to `True`, and serves over HTTP (for e.g. testing), the result is similar to the issue experienced here (i.e. the cookie will not set). In other words, a secure cookie will not save when not served over HTTPS.

Comment: Is it enough to to just use the session that comes with flask or do we have to use something like http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/121/ beaker session

Comment: This secret key can not still do the session persistent in blueprint.... @falsetru

Comment: @FahadAhammed, Sorry, I don't know about blueprint. Please post a separated question with detail so that others can answer you.

Comment: That's interesting! So WHY/HOW this tool here can decode the content of "session" cookie? The funfact (bug) of this tool, is that, when decoding, it must detect a dictionary (`SecureCookieSession`) composed at least of two keys. or else, it returns something like "[ERR: Not JSON data]". But the fact (strange) is, that the SESSION COOKIE CAN BE DECODED. The question is: how this happens?

Comment: @ivanleoncz, I didn't dig into the flask code. Please post a separate question for others can answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

As **@falsetru** mentioned, you have to set a secret key.

Before sending the `session` cookie to the user's browser, Flask signs the cookies cryptographically, and that doesn't mean that you cannot decode the cookie. I presume that Flask keeps track of the signed cookies, so it can perform it's own 'magic', in order to determine if the cookie that was sent along with the request (request headers), is a valid cookie or not.

Some methods that you may use, all related with Flask class instance, generally defined as `app`:

- defining the `secret_key` variable for `app` object

  ```
  app.secret_key = b'6hc/_gsh,./;2ZZx3c6_s,1//'
  ```
- using the `config()` method

  ```
  app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = b'6hc/_gsh,./;2ZZx3c6_s,1//'
  ```
- using an external configuration file for the entire Flask application

  ```
  $ grep pyfile app.py
  app.config.from_pyfile('flask_settings.cfg')

  $ cat flask_settings.py
  SECRET_KEY = b'6hc/_gsh,./;2ZZx3c6_s,1//'
  ```

Here's an example (an adaptation from [this article](https://overiq.com/flask/0.12/sessions-in-flask/)), focused on providing a more clearer picture of Flask `session` cookie, considering the participation of both Client and Server sides:

```
from flask import Flask, request, session                                       
import os                                                                       

app = Flask(__name__)                                                           

@app.route('/')                                                                 
def f_index():                                                               
    # Request Headers, sent on every request                                    
    print("\n\n\n[Client-side]\n", request.headers)                             
    if 'visits' in session:                                                     
        # getting value from session dict (Server-side) and incrementing by 1   
        session['visits'] = session.get('visits') + 1                           
    else:                                                                       
        # first visit, generates the key/value pair {"visits":1}                
        session['visits'] = 1                                                   
        # 'session' cookie tracked from every request sent                          
        print("[Server-side]\n", session)                                           
    return "Total visits:{0}".format(session.get('visits'))                     


if __name__ == "__main__":                                                      
    app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)                                             
    app.run()
```

Here's the output:

```
$ python3 sessions.py 
* Serving Flask app "sessions" (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: off
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

[Client-side]
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

[Server-side]
<SecureCookieSession {'visits': 1}>
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Oct/2018 14:27:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -


[Client-side]
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cookie: session=eyJ2aXNpdHMiOjF9.DqKHCQ.MSZ7J-Zicehb6rr8qw43dCVXVNA  # <--- session cookie
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

[Server-side]
<SecureCookieSession {'visits': 2}>
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Oct/2018 14:27:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

---

You may have noticed that in the example above, I'm using the `os` lib and the `urandom()` function, in order to generate Flask's secret key, right?

From [the official doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#sessions):

> **How to generate good secret keys**
>
> A secret key should be as random as possible. Your operating system has ways to generate pretty random data based on a cryptographic random generator. Use the following command to quickly generate a value for Flask.secret_key (or SECRET_KEY):
>
> $ python -c 'import os; print(os.urandom(16))'
>
> b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'

---

**PLUS NOTE**

> As you can see, the creators of Flask support the practice of using `os.urandom()` for building the Flask secret key, from older versions of the tool to its latest version. So: why **@joshlsullivan's** answer received downvotes (deserves an upvote) and why **@MikhailKashkin** writes that, using `os.urandom()` is terrible idea, are mysteries.

Answer (score 0):

Under `app = Flask(__name__)` place this: `app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)`.

Comment: @MikhailKashkin It was part of the official docs at one point.

Comment: I'm curious about: why this is a terrible idea? I got the point of having a different secret key for each instance of the application, but I can't see this as a security threat (please, open my eyes :)).
It's pretty bad that we still have people here on SO, just firing downvotes, without any explanation.

Comment: @ivanleoncz Agreed. Down votes are discouraged too. :-)

Comment: @joshlsullivan, take a look on my answer. It's definitely recommended by Flask, on its official doc ;).