# Flask redirect after login with token in header

Tags: python, http, flask

I'm new to web development and I'm trying to do a web server using flask for a school project. The problem is that, after login, I want to redirect to another page, which requires authentication, and pass the authorization token via the header. However, the page freezes, showing **Redirecting...** and says that I should be automatically redirected (which does not happen).

This is the code for the login POST and the redirected page.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login_verify():
    username = models.User.query.get(request.form['username'])
    if username == None or username.verify_password(request.form['password']) == False:
        abort(401)
    redir = redirect(url_for('map'))
    redir.headers = {'headers':username.encode_auth_token()}
    return redir

@app.route('/map')
def map():
    token = request.headers.get('headers')
    if token == None or models.User.decode_auth_token(token) == None:
        abort(403)
    deviceList = list(db.session.query(models.Location.terminalId.distinct()).all())
    return render_template('seeLocations.html',token = str(token),deviceList =  deviceList)
```

I have also tried this (and worked), but the token should not appear as an URL parameter.

```
return redirect(url_for('map',headers=username.encode_auth_token()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the session to accomplish what you're looking for

In your login you could save a token into session which can later be used in your route to map as needed.

```
session['token] = token
```

And to access it's value you could use

You can access it anywhere in the program just by

```
variable = session['token']
```

to unset the value and key from session you can use

```
session.pop('token' none)
```

more about flask sessions [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139910/using-session-in-flask-app&ved=0ahUKEwixvN2t8vDXAhWBrY8KHTB5BPMQjjgIfzAP&usg=AOvVaw1qbG17Yl3p6YvLexeZX06r)

Comment: Question was asked about tokens - im also wondering how would this be done use JWT - instead fo sessions..

Comment: sessions make the application lose the point of being REST - feature "Stateless" becomes void with using sessions.
Need to accomplish using JWT itself. even I wonder on how we could do it.

Comment: Even with JWT you'll have to store your tokens either in localstorage sessionstorage or at best cookies. Then in each requests you'll have to pass the token via headers.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue you are having here is you are overwritting the `headers` of the redirect response. This response had headers like `Location` set to tell the client where to go next, however you wiped them out with you assignment. This also why the client isn't redirecting automatically.

I think what you wanted, and would have worked was:

```
def login_verify():
    ...
    redir = redirect(url_for('map'))
    redir.headers['headers'] = username.encode_auth_token()
    return redir
```